# Difference between request and session in sp_blitzwho?

Tags: sql-server, sp-blitz

I'm starting to use sp_blitzwho, and I was wondering about a few of the columns.

1. There are a set of columns that start request_ such as request_writes, and then a set of columns that start session_, such as session_writes. Could someone explain the difference between these?
2. There is a column called wait_info. This holds a wait time and type, that I assume is what the proc call is waiting on? Is this correct?

If so what is the top_session_waits column showing? This column often has a few Waits in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the cool things about open source stored procedures like sp_BlitzWho is that you can actually see the source code. It's really useful when you have questions about where data is coming from and what it means.

If I open sp_BlitzWho and do a control-F for request_writes, for example, I see that it's:

```
COALESCE(r.writes, s.writes) AS request_writes,
```

And a little further down, I can see which tables the r and s aliases point to:

```
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions AS s
             LEFT JOIN sys.dm_exec_requests AS r
```

From there, you can hit the [documentation for sys.dm_exec_sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-sessions-transact-sql) and [sys.dm_exec_requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-requests-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), which explain that a request is a currently executing task (like a query), and a session is someone's connection that has been open for a while, which may have performed several requests over time.

As you suspected, wait_info is indeed what the query is waiting on - but rather than spoon-feeding you that one, I'll let you start your journey of reading the source code there. Hope that helps!

Comment: Brilliant thanks for the help, much more useful to know how to find these things out yourself. Taking on your advice, I quickly found that top_session_waits is for the entire connection duration and not just the query. Many thanks.